# Fit sum of cosines

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, predict

The problem is I have the function, that generates data that I need to predict. (initially I am given 168 values of the data and I need to predict the next 168 values)
The function looks like this [image] but return the floor of the shown formula

Where `m = (12,24,168,672)`, `a` are rational and `b` are integers

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/maksgeqll8) you can play with the formula in desmos

`a` affects the amount of vertical displacement of the cosine, `b` horizontally shifts cosines
So I defined the range for the b to be form 0 to 24, and for `a` (without `a0`) to be non-negative.

I am given 168 (from 0 to 167) points of this graph, and I need to predict the next 168 points (from 168 to 335)

I've tried to solve this, but my solution is either too slow (the limit is 1.5 seconds) or it predicts data with too big MSE, I'd say that the aim is for value less than 5

here I generate the data

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as mse


a0 = 0
a = 47, 0, 0, 0
b = 7, 8, 12, 5  # all ints
m = 12, 24, 168, 672  # predefined


def part(a, b, m, t):
    return a * np.cos((t / m + b / 24) * 2 * np.pi)


def load(t, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, b3, b4):
    res = a0
    res += part(a1, b1, m[0], t)
    res += part(a2, b2, m[1], t)
    res += part(a3, b3, m[2], t)
    res += part(a4, b4, m[3], t)

    return res.astype(int)


names = "a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, b3, b4".replace(" ", "").split(",")

n = 168
X_train = np.arange(n)
y_train = load(X_train, a0, *a, *b)  # np.array([load(x, a0, *a, *b) for x in X_train])

X_test = np.arange(n, 2*n)
y_test = load(X_test, a0, *a, *b)  # np.array([load(x, a0, *a, *b) for x in X_test])
```

As far as I understand if I can predict the arguments with decent enough quality / define the pretty small range, then the calculations will be faster, so what I did is

```py
max_diff = abs(y_train.max() - y_train.min())

guess = np.array([
    y_train.mean(), # a0

    1,                                              # a1
    max_diff / 2.,                                  # a2
    max_diff / 2.,                                  # a3
    (abs(y_train[0] - y_train[-1]) + max_diff) / 2, # a4

    0, # b1
    0, # b2
    0, # b3
    0, # b4
])

bounds = np.array([
    [-guess[4]*2, guess[4]*2],  # a0

    [0, guess[4]*2],  # a1
    [0, guess[4]*2],  # a2
    [0, guess[4]*2],  # a3
    [0, guess[4]*2],  # a4

    [0, 24],  # b1
    [0, 24],  # b2
    [0, 24],  # b3
    [0, 24],  # b4
])
```

But any approach to predict the data that I tried aren't reliable enough / work too long / produces too big MSE.

here I use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`

```py
from scipy import optimize

method = "trf"  # trf dogbox lm
print(f"using {method}")
params, params_covariance = optimize.curve_fit(
    load, X_train, y_train, method=method,
    # bounds=bounds.T, p0=guess,  # seems to work best without
)
```

and here I use `hyperopt.fmin`

```py
from hyperopt import hp, tpe, Trials, fmin

def objective(*params):
    """Objective function to minimize"""
    return mse(y_test, load(X_test, *params))

def objective2(args):
    return objective(*args)

space = [
    hp.uniform(name, *bound) for name, bound in zip(names, bounds)
]

tpe_algo = tpe.suggest
tpe_trials = Trials()

tpe_best = fmin(fn=objective2, space=space, algo=tpe_algo, trials=tpe_trials, max_evals=200)
params = tpe_best.values()
```

And the final test and output

```py
pattern = ", ".join([name + "={:.2f}" for name in names])

print('Fitted parameters:')
print(pattern.format(*params))
print('Original parameters:')
print(pattern.format(a0, *a, *b))

y_pred = load(X_test, *params)  #np.array([load(x, *params) for x in X_test])

mse_value = mse(y_test, y_pred)

print(mse_value)
```

Sometimes I can get 20, sometimes 600 and it may take 5 seconds, so not really nice.

So my question is how can I get better MSE-s / faster prediction times?
I'm a newbie in the field of data prediction so I apologize for my maybe stupid question, but I'd really like to get the direction or maybe a ready solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the `cos(x+y)` term, fold constants in new parameters, solve a linear regression problem, determine `b`, round the values of `b`, calculate the `a` coefficients.

Parameters to be estimated

```
a = 0, 15, 80, 50, 36
b = 7, 8, 12, 5  # all ints

t = np.arange(168, 355) # points where to evaluate
B = y = load(t, *a, *b).reshape(-1,1) # the input data
```

Find `a` and `b` from the data

```
A = np.zeros((9,len(t))) # basis for the linear regression
A[0] = 1; # coefficient of a[0], a constant
for i in range(1,5):
    # terms in the sum
    A[2*i-1] = np.cos(2*np.pi * t / m[i-1])
    A[2*i] = -np.sin(2*np.pi * t / m[i-1])
# solve the least square linear regression problem
coefs, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(A.T, B, rcond=None)

# best float b
b_direct = np.arctan2(coefs[2::2], coefs[1::2]) * 12 / np.pi
# best int b
b_int = np.round(b_direct) % 24
# construct a
a_hat = np.vstack([coefs[0:1], np.hypot(coefs[2::2], coefs[1::2]) / np.cos((b_direct - b_int)*np.pi / 12)])
```

output

```
(array([[ 0.28049711],
        [15.0565856 ],
        [79.52089864],
        [49.74561099],
        [36.11873401]]),
 array([[  6.98003412],
        [  8.00154676],
        [-11.99776252],
        [  4.97734272]]))
```

Comment: have you planned on using `mask` in the `projection`? It's just unused.

Comment: hehe, yes initially I planned I would create a mask to multiply by the FFT but then I preferred to only give the coefficients. I'll fix

Comment: `rounded_b` is `b_` in `projection`?

Comment: `rounded_b` is that equation for `b_`, `b` the same equation without `np.round`.

Comment: Think where is the nearest point to a point `(r * cos(theta), r * sin(theta))` in the x axis, you draw a vertical line to connect the points, the solution I gave will draw a chord in the circle, to the point (r, 0), but the exact value would be (r*cos(theta), 0), the solution I gave is already close, the relative error will be at most `(1-cos(pi/12))`.

Comment: well, what I can already say that mse is pretty good without the correction, but I'm gonna try to implement the correction anyways, it seems to be easy :)

Comment: I added `unrounded_b = np.array([((24 / (np.pi * 2)) * np.angle(Y[N // (2 * mi)])) % 24 for mi in m])` and before return added `a_[1:] = a_[1:] / np.cos(unrounded_b - b_)` but it did almost nothing. If we `print(np.cos(unrounded_b - b_))` then we see something like `[0.99998114 0.99999997 0.99999926 0.99999981]` and as I understand it is intended. So there's no real need to add anything?

Comment: Well, the problem is that initially, I don't know the parameters (`a`, `b`)  and the only data given to me is the function value at 168 points from 0 to 167, and therefore `assert(N % (2*672) == 0)` cannot be satisfied

Comment: Well in that case you have to use regular linear regression. Updated the answer.

Comment: Because the number of points you have does is not enough to do the FFT properly.